# Python socket - downloading files only work in chrome

Tags: python, file, sockets, websocket

So I created a code which a client uploads a file to the server folder and he has an option to download it back, [it works perfectly fine in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIMia.png), [I click on the item I want to download and it downloads it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtXDF.png)

```
def send_image(request, cs):
    request = request.split('=')
    try:
        name = request[1]
    except:
        name = request[0]
    print('using send_iamge!')
    print('Na ' + name)
    path = 'C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\webroot\\uploads' + '\\file-name=' + name
    print(path)
    with open(path, 'rb') as re:
        print('exist!')
        read = re.read()
        cs.send(read)
```

the code above reads the file that you choose and sends the data as bytes to the client back.
In chrome, it downloads the file as I showed you already but in for example internet explorer, it just [prints the data to the client and doesn't download it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvu90.png) The real question is why doesn't it just prints the data in chrome, why does it download it and doesn't print it as internet explorer does and how can I fix it?(for your info: all the files that I download have the name file-name before them that's why I put it there)

http request:
UPDATE:

```
 POST /upload?file-name=Screenshot_2.png HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3534
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,he;q=0.7
```

Comment: The code is missing any context. If there is an actual HTTP response header send before this then please show what was sent. If you did not send a HTTP response header then this will be interpreted as HTTP/0.9 by the browsers which support this protocol (obsolete since 25 years). In this case the behavior could be anything since HTTP/0.9 has no concept of Content-Type, Content-Disposition or anything like this which are needed for proper downloads.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the http is sending a post request  HTTP1.1 that's not the problem for sure the request is good but if you insist I'll add the request

Comment: Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
   Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If
   and only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
   recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
   content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
   resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
   treat it as type "application/octet-stream". - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: @lainatnavi I posted the request

Comment: Send to the client socket this header `Content-Type : application/octet-stream`. `cs.send('Content-Type : application/octet-stream')`

Comment: @lainatnavi when? before the request?

Comment: In `cs.send()` I think you're writing to the client's socket. It should be in the header, before the body. header and body are be separated by one line. So before `with open...` send the content-type header.

Comment: @lainatnavi Yeah I changed it still doesn't work ill update the request above and tell me if that's what you meant it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you don't send a HTTP/1 response but a HTTP/0.9 response (Note that I'm talking about the response send from the server not the request send from the client). A HTTP/1 response consists of a HTTP header and a HTTP body, similar to how a HTTP request is constructed. A HTTP/0.9 response instead only consists of the actual body, i.e. no header and thus no meta information in the header which tell the browser what to do with the body.

HTTP/0.9 is obsolete for 25 years but some browsers still support it. When a browser gets a HTTP/0.9 request it could anything with it since there is no defined meaning from the HTTP header. Browsers might try to interpret is as HTML, as plain text, offer it for download, refuse it in total ... - whatever.

The way to fix the problem is to send an actual HTTP response header before sending the body, i.e. something like this

```
 cs.send("HTTP/1.0 200 ok\r\nContent-type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n")
 with open(path, 'rb') as re:
     ...
     cs.send(read)
```

In any case: HTTP is way more complex than you might think. There are established libraries to deal with this complexity. If you insist on not using any library please study the standard in order  to avoid such problems.

Comment: No it sends http1.1 you can see it
POST /upload?file-name=Screenshot_2.png HTTP/1.1

Comment: It works I just don't understand why, where do I send the 0.9 response?

Comment: @Patch I think Steffen is referring to the response header, not the request header. If you don't set any headers in the response it is considered as just the response body by HTTP

Comment: @Patch: "I just don't understand why..."* - likely because you have no idea of how HTTP works. Do yourself a favor and read at least the Wikipedia article which has an [example of a proper response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Server_response). Better yet, use libraries like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to deal with the HTTP protocol instead of implementing it on your own.